# How to specify proper mime for javascript in apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, mime, mime-type

I'm trying to set up mod_mime for javascript. My webserver returns this content-type for js files:

```
Content-Type:application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
```

so obviously the directive

```
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 year"
```

specified in `.htaccess` doesn't work.

So, any ideas how to specify mime type in such case?

PS: the same (adding of `; charset=utf-8`) happens also with `.css`, but all the binary types (images) work fine.

Comment: Sorry, but what mime-type are you trying to change it to?  What is your problem with it report utf-8?

Comment: @Zoredache: I don't want to change - I want to set up the cache expiration date for jss and css and don't know how to specify mime-type for them.